# Error in ngrx immediately after upgrading to Angular 7

Tags: angular, upgrade, ngrx, angular7

`error TS2345: Argument of type '(source$: Observable<RootState>) => Observable<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<RootChildState, any>'`

Everything was working perfectly prior to the upgrade.

What's causing this error ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: This is not meant to be on stackoverflow. You can search for similar issues on the ngrx github repo and create new one if not already existing.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a bug. Apparently `Support Requests` should be on StackOverflow: `Support Requests should not be opened as issues and should be handled in the following ways: StackOverflow... Gitter... etc` https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/new?template=support-request.md